# How is Cawas's GetOrAddComponent more efficent than mine?

Tags: c#, comparison, unity-game-engine, performance

Cawas's GetOrAddComponent extension method (http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/GetOrAddComponent) has helped me a lot (in particular, how to create a generic method and introducing me to extension methods), but I'm curious as to how it would be more efficient than mine:

```
public static T GetOrAddComponent<T>(this GameObject obj) where T:Component
{
    if(obj.GetComponent<T>() == null)
    {
        return obj.AddComponent<T>();
    }
    else
    {
        return obj.GetComponent<T>();
    }
}
```

In my example, a variable isn't be created and stored in memory, so wouldn't that make mine more efficient? Or is there something I'm missing out on? (This is likely, I'm only a beginner :P)

Comment: The background of the question is no longer valid; the linked article has been updated to use a null coalescing operator (`??`) instead of a variable. [This is a link to the old version.](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=GetOrAddComponent&oldid=16444)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked method makes one call to `GetComponent`; the code you've pasted here makes two such calls. That's a big enough difference that it might show up under heavy load.

Depending on the compiler, comparing a local variable is negligibly different or not at all different from comparing an anonymous value. In the end, it's all being processed on the stack.

Comment: Hmmm, I think I see... So essentially, use one way to save CPU, the other to save memory?

Comment: Not exactly. `GetComponent` requires both CPU time and memory; it also sometimes allocates a small amount of heap memory. It's a much bigger difference than the local var, which (depending on your compiler) may turn out to be no difference at all.